# iOS - Create Bouncing Animation Both Ways On Tapping Table Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation, uitableview

In my app, I implement Snapchat style swipe-to-chat functionality. When a user swipe's right on a friend's `UITableViewCell`, the top `UIView` will scroll while showing a chat icon image behind it. When the full chat icon image is shown, the user can finish the scroll to the chat view. The same thing happens when the user swipes left for other info about the friend.

However, I'm afraid that my users won't see this as an intuitive or obvious functionality. Snapchat knows this too, and that's why they make a friend's `UITableViewCell` bounce when tapped to give the user a hint that they can swipe to chat.

I need to do the same thing for my app, but have the top `UIView` bounce in both directions when the user taps the `UITableViewCell`. This will hint the user that they can swipe right to chat and left to see the friend's info.

How do I get this done? I've never done animations before.

***PROGRESS:***

I was able to get somewhat of what I wanted in an ugly way that doesn't look much like Snapchat's bouncing animation in the following code:

```
    //1.)Show full chat icon
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

        self.myContentView.center = CGPointMake(self.myContentView.center.x + self.chatButton.frame.size.width, self.myContentView.center.y);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        //2.)Show full location icon
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

            self.myContentView.center = CGPointMake(self.myContentView.center.x - self.chatButton.frame.size.width - self.locationButton.frame.size.width, self.myContentView.center.y);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            //3.)Show half of chat icon
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.125 animations:^{

                self.myContentView.center = CGPointMake(self.myContentView.center.x + self.locationButton.frame.size.width + self.chatButton.frame.size.width/2, self.myContentView.center.y);

            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                //4.)Show half of location icon
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.125 animations:^{

                    self.myContentView.center = CGPointMake(self.myContentView.center.x - self.chatButton.frame.size.width/2 - self.locationButton.frame.size.width/2, self.myContentView.center.y);

                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                    //5.)Show quarter of chat icon
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0625 animations:^{

                        self.myContentView.center = CGPointMake(self.myContentView.center.x + self.locationButton.frame.size.width/2 + self.chatButton.frame.size.width/4, self.myContentView.center.y);

                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                        //6.)Show quarter of location icon
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0625 animations:^{

                            self.myContentView.center = CGPointMake(self.myContentView.center.x - self.chatButton.frame.size.width/4 - self.locationButton.frame.size.width/4, self.myContentView.center.y);

                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                            //7.)Return to normal state/position
                            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.03125 animations:^{

                                self.myContentView.center = CGPointMake(self.myContentView.center.x + self.locationButton.frame.size.width/4, self.myContentView.center.y);

                            }];

                        }];

                    }];

                }];

            }];

        }];

    }];
```

I don't like that I have to nest all these animations. Is there an easier way to do this? Maybe I missed a springy or bouncy animation that Apple provides to its developers to work with?

Comment: Did you try with `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` class method from `UIView`? The `view` parameter is the view you want to animate, `duration` is the duration in seconds of the animation (`CGFloat`), `options` is a value from the `UIViewAnimationOptions` enumeration, `animations` is the final state you want and `completion` is what you want to do when the transition finishes. The two last parameters are blocks.

Comment: Check the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:

Comment: Wow! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I'll try this out and update this question with my progress if I'm having trouble.

Comment: Maybe instead of declaring that way, you would want to declare blocks inside variables and use them like functions. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html it's basically the same, but a lot more readable and reusable since they work like functions.

Comment: Or even methods that you could define in an object and just call them and pass the blocks as reference.